# Code behind OleDb UPDATE query not updating record using WHERE clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 developing an ASP.NET project using C# for my code behind. I performed some searching, but did not find anything that helped answer this problem. When I click the update button, the code processes but does not actually update the record. Appreciate any guidance where I am going wrong with this code.

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Coins.mdb;"))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand UpdateCoins = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                UpdateCoins.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                UpdateCoins.CommandText = "UPDATE [Coins] SET CoinName = ?, CurrencyType = ?, CoinType = ?, CoinValue = ?, YearIssued = ?, DateAcquired = ?, Email = ? WHERE ID = 12";

                UpdateCoins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoinName", txtCoinName.Text);
                UpdateCoins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrencyType", txtCurrencyType.Text);
                UpdateCoins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoinType", txtCoinType.Text);
                UpdateCoins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoinValue", txtCoinValue.Text);
                UpdateCoins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YearIssued", txtYearIssued.Text);
                UpdateCoins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAcquired", txtDateAcquired.Text);
                UpdateCoins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);

                UpdateCoins.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                UpdateCoins.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("DisplayCoin.aspx");
}
```

Comment: All your columns are character typed?

Comment: Soner, No specific character typing done, but I am able to use INSERT queries on two other aspx pages as well as SELECT queries without issue. It seems to be an issue unique to this specific code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not even think about the page_load event affecting my code. I changed it to the following and it works without issue. Thank you for suggestions.

```
        protected override void  OnSaveStateComplete(EventArgs e)
```